# Set a Value Before Button is Pushed

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, binding

I'm working with Silverlight 4, C# and XAML. I have an external control that filters my date and time, although it doesn't work as planned.

It only updates my DateTime value when you tab out/lose focus or when you hit the search button twice. How could I make it so when you hit the search button the value updates right away?

Here's the XAML code I'm using,

```
<toolkit:NumericUpDown Grid.Column="2" Margin="10" Value="{Binding ElementName=DateTimeframeElement, Path=DateTimeframe.TimeFrameMeasure, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks,
Jason

Ohh, sorry intellisense wasn't working for UpdateSourceTrigger because I wasn't using it properly, thank you!

Comment: Perhaps the version of Silverlight you use supports the binding property: `UpdateTrigger=PropertyChanged`, however if it is in a DataGrid you could also use `DataGrid.CommitEdit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just need to add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to your binding.